# Address family not Supported Exception Reproduce

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

Hi I'm trying to reproduce addressFamily Exception

```
std::auto_ptr<UdpSocket> s_StatusSocket;
//.......
//.......
try
{
    s_StatusSocket->send(&f.addr, reqBuf, reqLen);

}
catch (const SystemException& se)
{
    string exceptionMessage=se.what();  
    if(exceptionMessage.find("ddress family"))
    {   
        //Finally THrown
    }
}
```

for that i'm using iptables to block the IP's,

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.0.1   -j DROP
service iptables save
```

Doing so there is no exception is thrown on the send block, do let me know how to reproduce address family not supported in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile a kernel without IPv6. Or use an otherwise unsupported address family.

You can't use iptables - that's got absolutely nothing to do with which address families are supported. You need to actually pass in an address that isn't supported when you call `socket(2)`. Note also that if you read the man page for `send()`, you'll observe it doesn't return `EAFNOSUPPORT`! You've misread the documentation - the `EAFNOSUPPORT` error is returned by `socket(2)`, `connect(2)`, and `socketpair(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) protocol offers no guarantees about delivery of packets.  There is no confirmation of receipt by the intended recipient.  As far as the `UdpSocket` is concerned it has sent the packets.  It is not aware that IPTables is throwing them away.

If you want to know whether data has made it to the intended recipient you should use [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

Comment: so there is no way to reproduce it